# Border container and card

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I've the following code:

```
return Card(
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0),
        ),
        child: InkWell(
          onTap: () {
            ....
          },
          child: Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              border: Border(
                  top: BorderSide(
                color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                width: 3.0,
              )),
              //borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(topLeft: const Radius.circular(5.0), topRight: const Radius.circular(5.0)),
            ),
            height: 133,
            child: ...,
          ),
        ));
  }
```

The problem is that I am trying to set a color on the top border and assign a border radius of 5. As far as I am aware, I can't assign a color to the top border in the card. You have to set it all the way around. But you can do this on the container. The problem is that adding a radius to the Container makes the content inside it disappear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's an interesting mechanic... Though not ideal, I suppose you could wrap your child with a `Column` and make your own custom border element, so it doesn't clash with your content.

Something like this:

```
class MyTopBorder extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
          topLeft: const Radius.circular(5.0),
          topRight: const Radius.circular(5.0),
        ),
        color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
      ),
      height: 3.0,
    );
  }
}
```

and then add it to your `Card`:

```
Card(
  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0),
  ),
  child: InkWell(
    onTap: () {
      // ...
    },
    child: Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        MyTopBorder(),
        Container(
          height: 133,
          child: Text("..."),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ),
),
```